# Working nicely with Enums and HEX values

Tags: c#, enums, hex, maintainability

I have a list of enums as follows:

```
public enum EventID : uint
{
    SAMPLE_EVENT_1 = 0xDCCA0000,
    SAMPLE_EVENT_2 = 0xDCCB0001,
    SAMPLE_EVENT_3 = 0xDCCA0002,
    SAMPLE_EVENT_4 = 0xDCC00003,
    SAMPLE_EVENT_5 = 0xDCCA0004,
    ...
}
```

The hex value for each enum is deciphered as follows:

```
/// DCC X XXXX 
/// --- - ----
///  |  |  |--> Notification ID (0x0000 to 0xFFFF)
///  |  |-----> Notification Type (0x0 to 0xA)
///  |--------> Sub-system ID (0xDCC)
```

What is the best way to assign values to the `enum`'s, such that adding `enum`'s later won't mean reassigning all the values. The only Sub-system ID, and Notification Type are chosen, the Notification ID should be automatically assigned.

For example, it might get annoying if there were thousands of `enum`'s and I had to number them by hand or renumber them if adding an `enum` in the middle.

Thanks.

Comment: What's you motivation for having such huge enums? I have strong feeling that you are abusing enums in a way they are not designed for.

Comment: @JakubŠturc They are used to signal another sub-system of an event such as a hardware event, or data change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you asked me, you shouldn't be encoding this data in your enum values.  It would be better to apply attributes the them instead where you could get this information.  Let the actual value of the enum represent the `NotificationId` to get the automatically assigned values.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple=false)]
public class SubsystemIdAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SubsystemIdAttribute(ushort value)
    {
        this.Value = (ushort)(value & 0xFFF);
    }

    public ushort Value { get; private set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class NotificationTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public NotificationTypeAttribute(byte value)
    {
        this.Value = (byte)(value & 0xF);
    }

    public byte Value { get; private set; }
}

public enum EventId
{
    [SubsystemId(0xDCC)] [NotificationType(0xA)] SAMPLE_EVENT_1,
    [SubsystemId(0xDCC)] [NotificationType(0xB)] SAMPLE_EVENT_2,
    [SubsystemId(0xDCC)] [NotificationType(0xA)] SAMPLE_EVENT_3,
    [SubsystemId(0xDCC)] [NotificationType(0x0)] SAMPLE_EVENT_4,
    [SubsystemId(0xDCC)] [NotificationType(0xA)] SAMPLE_EVENT_5,
}

public static class EventIdExtensions
{
    public static ushort GetSubsystemId(this EventId eventId)
    {
        return GetAttributeValue(eventId, (SubsystemIdAttribute a) => a.Value);
    }

    public static byte GetNotificationType(this EventId eventId)
    {
        return GetAttributeValue(eventId, (NotificationTypeAttribute a) => a.Value);
    }

    private static TValue GetAttributeValue<TAttribute, TValue>(EventId eventId, Func<TAttribute, TValue> selector)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        return typeof(EventId).GetField(eventId.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(false)
            .OfType<TAttribute>()
            .Select(selector)
            .Single();
    }
}
```

To get the values of the attributes, call the appropriate extension methods.

```
var eventId = EventId.SAMPLE_EVENT_3;
var subsystemId = eventId.GetSubsystemId();           // 0xDCC
var notificationType = eventId.GetNotificationType(); // 0xA
```

Comment: I really like the idea of using attributes, although I'm not very familiar with them. Is it possible to have 2 attributes for each enum, one for subsystem ID, and one for notification type? This way the notification ID would be incremented automatically. If possible could you edit your answer to show how this is done?

Comment: Yeah, sure.  That would actually be a lot more cleaner IMHO (just more verbose).  Let me make the necessary changes.

Comment: Also, how do you get the attribute value of an enum? For example to be printed.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking something like `[Subsystem(0xDCC)][Type(0xA)] SAMPLE_EVENT_1`. Is it possible to have multiple custom attributes for an enum?

Comment: Updated showing how you could define and apply the attributes and get their values.

Comment: Ryan: I am not sure if automatic assignment of notification ID via attributes is possible but if so I strongly recommend you to not let compiler do it for you. Your ids would be used by some external system (if not there is no reason for their existence). By letting compiler do the magic you are creating dependency between your compiler and external system.

Comment: @JakubŠturc Thanks for the heads up. I will look into my exact scenario and see if multiple attributes is needed. But you may be right that static values are needed, since external systems will rely on these values.

Answer (score 0):

Enums only auto-increment by 1, so you'd have to keep them in order by sub-system, then notification type, then notification id, and only when there are gaps would you assign. So to keep order proper, your above enum would look like this:

```
public enum EventID : uint
{
    SAMPLE_EVENT_1 = 0xDCCA0000,
    SAMPLE_EVENT_3 = 0xDCCA0002,
    SAMPLE_EVENT_5 = 0xDCCA0004,
    SAMPLE_EVENT_2 = 0xDCCB0001,
    SAMPLE_EVENT_4 = 0xDCC00003,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that purpose of your enums is to give a names to the events with specific codes. The question is what is the canonical source of association between names and codes. If it is you (or your code) I don't see any reason to renumber. If it comes from some external source (e.g. documentation) try to deploy some code generation (e.g. [T4 templates](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with [Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491760/nicely-working-with-enums-and-hex-values-c/7492054#7492054) this is imho much more cleaner design

```
public class EventId
{
    public static readonly SAMPLE_EVENT_1 = new EventId(0xDCC, 0xA);
    public static readonly SAMPLE_EVENT_2 = new EventId(0xDCC, 0xA);
    public static readonly SAMPLE_EVENT_3 = new EventId(0xDCC, 0xA);
    public static readonly SAMPLE_EVENT_4 = new EventId(0xDCC, 0xA);

    public readonly ushort SubSystemId;
    public readonly byte NotificationType;
    public readonly ushort NotificationId;

    private static ushort notificationCounter = 0;

    private EventId(ushort subSystemId, byte notificationType)
    {
        this.SubSystemId = subSystemId;
        this.NotificationType= notificationType;
        this.NotificationId = notificationCounter++;
    }
}
```

But of course you creating dependency between compiler and `NotificationId` which you probably don't like.